# Found 2 major bugs in magento 2 when creating orders through the admin, temp solution anybody?

Tags: magento2

Issue 1.

On a multistore with different prices when you hit the button update qty the wrong price is suddenly assigned to the products.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15846

Issue 2.

On a multistore with different tablerates the wrong shipping price is used. Looks like he always uses website ID 1.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16604

Just wondering if anybody found a solution I can use and then pray the dev team will really fix it :-)